# Phonegap - Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, build, phonegap

Command finished with error code 1: /project/gradlew cdvBuildDebug,-b,/project/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
Error: /project/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/project/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15:21-54: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

The strange think is that it worked until yesterday

Comment: Update your compile SDK version.

Comment: What version? And, I'm building on https://build.phonegap.com. I don't understand. Tks

Comment: No idea how phonegap works. You're getting this error because the library you're using is referencing resources from a newer SDK. You need to configure your project to have a higher (preferably 27) compile SDK version.